# How to solve the inequality arising in an arithmetic question?

Tags: inequality

How to solve the inequality?

Given:

$S_K=3x $

$ S_S \ge 3x+20$

And we have the equation:

$300-3x=(S_S+S_K)*\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Plug in $S_K$ and solve for $S_S$, you should get a second equality for $S_K$. Are you solving for $x$ or what?

Comment: @MattiP. Yes solving for x

Comment: @Soumee Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

From the given $S_K=3x$ we have

- $300-3x=(S_S+3x)\cdot\frac{3}{2}\implies200-2x=S_S+3x\implies S_S=200-5x$

then

- $S_S \ge 3x+20\implies 200-5x \ge3x+20$